# Apache rotatelogs.exe fails with "Couldn't start ErrorLog process"

Tags: apache-2.4

I am trying to make apache rotatelogs.exe work  (Apache 2.4, windows 10 pro)

This is the configuration:

```
ErrorLog "C:/Temp/logs/error.log"
ErrorLog "|C:/Temp/rotatelogs C:/Temp/logs/error.log 10"  #option 1

<VirtualHost ...>
    ErrorLog "|C:/Temp/rotatelogs C:/Temp/logs/error.log 10"  #option 2
</VirtualHost>
```

The folder where apache is located is inside "C:/Program files (x86)/apache/...", so just in case there is an issue with escaping the spaces, I moved the location to the temp folder. (in addition to the rotatelogs.exe)

I am getting the error:

```
(OS 2)The system cannot find the file specified.  : AH00089: Couldn't start ErrorLog process 'C:/Temp/rotatelogs C:/Temp/logs/error.log 10'.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I am starting apache as a service. I gave full control permission to `Local Service` to the `C:/Temp/logs` folder.

If I use option #1 (ErrorLog directive outside the VirtualHost, then no ErrorLog is created, and apache fails to start.

If I use option #2 (ErrorLog directive inside the VirtualHost, then `C:/Temp/logs/error.log` is created, but and fails to start with the same `Couldn't start ErrorLog process` error.

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Did you get the solution of this, I am also facing same issue.

Comment: I think this works
```
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -l logs/errorlog.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400"
ErrorLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe -n 20 logs/errorlog.%Y-%m-%d.log"
```
I tested a long time ago

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Apache httpd on Windows but I would  expect that there the names of binaries get an `.exe` extension and you need to use `c:/Temp/rotatelogs.exe` rather than `c:/Temp/rotatelogs` (when that is the path where the rotatelogs program/binary is installed).